# Angular ui.bootstrap.modal and mousedown

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've checked the Angular UI modal window implementation and don't see that it's swallowing up the `mousedown` event anywhere, though I'm no javascript guru, and it might be I overlooked it. It binds to the `keydown` event, but I saw no `mousedown` binding.

I cannot get the modal to be draggable using [this native Angular draggable directive from the Angular site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).  The directive is being invoked when the page loads, but the directive's `mousedown` handler never fires when I try to drag the window around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular UI modal has its own template inside which your template (i.e. that you pass to $modal({template:"xyz"}) ) is **transcluded** .

you can open angular-bootstrap code and see it.
So for drag and drop to work you will have to use that directive on the template of $modal

Comment: Thank you for this information on the transcluded template.

Comment: It leaves the backdrop shadow behind.